# C# Web App: Custom Logger for external logging

Tags: c#, logging, web-applications, aws-lambda

Hello c# experts,

I'm writing an AWS lambda function in c# which requires external logging (I have to write all my logs to an external endpoint). I have been reading many articles about the best practices. Also I did some research on c# libraries such as NLog, Log4Net etc (Some libraries aren't compatible with .Net Core).

My main requirement is that I do not want to pass a **Logger** object around everywhere in my code. Instead, I should be able to write an external log more like a static method call (Ex: **Logger.sendLog("log message");**).

Considering the above requirement and the threading issues, I have decided to implement my Logger as a singleton which works fine at the moment. But, I'm curious to know if there are any particular issues with this design. Please let me know if there is a better way to implement a custom Logger class which writes external logs.

Thank you.

```
    interface ILogger
    {
        void init();
        void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo);
        void sendLog(Dictionary<LogKey, object> payload);
    }

     public sealed class Logger : ILogger
        {
            private static readonly Logger instance = new Logger();
            private static LogObject logObject;

            public static Logger Instance
            {
                get
                {
                    return instance;
                }
            }

            public void init()
            {
                logObject = new LogObject();
                logObject.appId = AppConfig.appId;
                logObject.application = AppConfig.appName;
                logObject.version = AppConfig.appVersion;
                logObject.environment = EnvConfig.Instance.clientConfig.environment;
                logObject.clientName = EnvConfig.Instance.clientConfig.clientName;
            }

            public void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo)
            {
                logObject.userId = userInfo.userId;
                logObject.userName = userInfo.userName;
            }

            public void sendLog(Dictionary<LogKey, object> payload)
            {
                setTimeStamp();
                logObject.log_level = LogLevel.INFO.ToString();
                logObject.payload = payload;
                deliverLog(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logObject));
                resetLogObj();
            }

            private void deliverLog(string logStr)
            {
                // External API call here
            }

            private void setTimeStamp()
            {
                logObject.timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }

            private void resetLogObj()
            {
                logObject.payload = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what the need is for an `ILogger` interface if everything in the codebase will be coupled to `Logger` directly (by having static references to it).

Comment: This isn't thread safe (if that matters to you). Since there is one static `logObject` in the class, if concurrent calls to `sendLog` happen at the same time the information in `logObject` could be from either payload. Either `lock` the contents of `sendLog` or create a local `LogObject ` in the method and send that.

Comment: Also, one nit-pick is that c# convention always use PascalCase for methods and properties. So, `sendLog` should be `SendLog`, `deliverLog` should be `DeliverLog`, etc. This doesn't affect the code execution, but keeping close to convention makes the code more readable to other developers.

Comment: Also, also (last one I promise), this question isn't appropriate for StackOverflow it should be asked on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: thanks @Lithium: Is it a good practice to create multiple log objects for each log being written? I only keep the base log details in the static logObject.

Comment: @OrangeTree It not ideal here. Personally, if I were to create a local object instead of locking, I would create a container object that has the properties that change each log (timestamp, log_level, payload) and a reference to an object containing the properties that don't change (appid, application, user, etc.).